# Godot Engine, 2D игра, сохранение

Tags: godot

Я хочу сделать игру. Смысл в том чтобы нажимать на кнопку и число с нажатиями увеличивалось. Я это сделал. Осталось разобраться с сохранением этого кол-ва нажатий.

Вот какой код получился благодаря ответу:

```
extends Control

var file = File.new()
var content = load_data()
var count = content # Нафига сделал не знаю


func _on_Button_pressed():
    count += 1
    save_data()
    load_data()
    $Count.text = 'НАЖАТИЙ: ' + str(content)


func save_data():
    file.open("user://count.txt", File.WRITE)
    file.store_line(str(count))
    file.close()

func load_data():
    file.open("user://count.txt", File.READ)
    content = file.get_line().to_int()
    file.close()
    return content
```

Comment: Ну например начать с чтения документации? https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/tutorials/io/saving_games.html

Comment: Я её читал, нифига не понял